# updated to ruby 2.4.1 via rvm but Atom still on 2.3.1

Tags: ruby, rvm, atom-editor

I have restarted atom and computer. There doesn't seem to be a config value for this. How would I update atom to reflect this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried these three things?

in ~/.bashrc (via [this github issue](https://github.com/atom-archive/terminal/issues/38)):

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or, install the [project-shell-env atom plugin](https://atom.io/packages/000-project-shell-env).

or, have rvm create a [wrapper script](https://rvm.io/deployment/init-d) that you can configure as your ruby command as described at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/JoshCheek/ff2a4e82587b68f3b190).

Comment: thx - I saw those but none of them worked for me. It actually is very strange that it's sticking at 2.3.1. I ended up just adding `rvm default 2.4.1` to my ~/.bash_profile until I can dig through it more. VERY ugly but seems to work.